# PyQT, TensorFlow, CX_Freeze сборка без консоли

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

Собираю программу на keras с gui с помощью cx_freeze.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо скрыть окно консоли во время работы программы. Делаю это через base="Win32GUI". 
Но тогда сталкиваюсь с ошибкой TF "NoneType" object has no attribute write (я понимаю, т.к. консоли нет).
С выводом консоли все работает в штатном режиме.

Скрин ошибки прилагаю. Подскажите, как можно решить проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python\tcl\tk8.6'

executables = [Executable('main.pyw', icon='ico.ico', base="Win32GUI")]
build_exe_options = {
      "includes": [
            "cv2",
            'numpy.core._methods',
            'numpy.lib.format',
            'threading',
            'PyQt5',
            'idna.idnadata',
            'pyperclip',
            'keras.preprocessing',
            'tensorflow',
            'scipy.sparse.csgraph',
            'ctypes',
            'os'
      ], "include_files": [r"C:\Python\DLLs\tcl86t.dll", r"C:\Python\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]}

setup(name='B',
      version='1.0',
      description='F',
      executables=executables,
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options})
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
from keras.preprocessing import image
sys.stderr = stderr
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```